# SVG text vertical alignment differs depending on context

Tags: html, svg, raphael

I have a SVG object (generated with RaphaelJS) which shows correctly when inserted in one  HTML page.

When creating the same SVG using the same code in a different page, text appears incorrectly aligned in vertical.

I have checked all styles and attributes affecting SVG and the HTML containing the diagram, but I haven't found any significant difference. Also, I thought that SVG should not be affected by the CSS rules of parent HTML elements.

Here is a picture of the issue. On the left, the correctly rendered diagram. On the right, the text appears incorrectly aligned (not centered). These two SVG objects  appear in different iframes of the same document (I have put them together for the picture).

[image: SVG text alignment issues]

Edit: I have noticed that the Y coordinates of text elements are indeed different:

```
<!-- Incorrect -->
<text x="362" y="71" text-anchor="end" style="font: normal normal normal 10px/normal Arial; text-anchor: end; " stroke="none" fill="#000000"><tspan>MQ</tspan></text> 
<!-- Correct -->
<text x="362" y="74.5" text-anchor="end" style="font: normal normal normal 10px/normal Arial; text-anchor: end; " font="10px &quot;Arial&quot;" stroke="none" fill="#000000"><tspan>MQ</tspan></text>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please add your Raphaël code.

Comment: Note that there is no 'font' attribute in svg, it's a CSS shorthand only.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Raphael code is way too complex and I have no time to prepare an isolated reproduction case :/. Thanks.

Comment: @ErikDahlström those style attributes are added by Raphael, but they do have an effect (I can see the font family changes if I remove the style attribute, but not size or positioning).

Comment: @jjmontes yes, 'font' is allowed inside 'style' attributes, but not like in your second text element, [... font="10px &quot;Arial&quot;" ...]. That should have no effect at all. Anyway, you need to add the script code that generated the text elements for it to be possible to properly answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG elements in the same document (which is the case if you use Raphaël) do get CSS applied from its parents, as well as stylerules from stylesheets used in that document that happen to target svg elements.

Have you tried using a debugging tool such as opera dragonfly, webkit inspector or mozilla firebug to inspect what styles are being applied to those text elements?

At least the following properties would affect the text baseline:

- dominant-baseline
- alignment-baseline
- baseline-shift

Comment: I'm using both webkit inspector and mozilla firebug. They both show differences in the "y" value (3.5 px) between the text elements of the two SVG objects.

Comment: The 3,5 pixel difference seems to be introduced by Raphael. I ended up correcting the Y values manually (didn't have time to find why that difference was introduced depending on the context). Thanks!